# Overriding the _mint function of ERC20

Tags: solidity, erc-20, function-override

I am trying to override the _mint function of the ERC20.sol as i want. Unfortunately, i am getting an error which I will attach below.

Does anybody know how can I overcome this issue?

Here is my function which is intended to add some rules to the original _mint function of the ERC20.sol

```
function _mint(address _owner, uint _amount) override public pure{
    
    if (_amount > 0 && isContained[_owner] == false) {
        tokenHolders.push(_owner);
        isContained[_owner] = true;
    }
    
    _mint(_owner, _amount);
}
```

And this is the error i am given

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is self explanatory.

You want to override the following function :

```
function _mint(address account, uint256 amount) internal virtual
{...}
```

But your definition is :

```
function _mint(address _owner, uint256 _amount) override public pure
{...}
```

Your function needs to be internal too (matching the signature and visibility of the function it overrides)

Try like this :

```
function _mint(address _owner, uint256 _amount) internal virtual override
{...}
```